# Binary flag with two conditions r

Tags: r

Hy!
My sample data is like this:

```
Date       Quantity Price 
2010/01/01    1        4.00
2010/01/02    5        3.00
2010/01/03    3        3.00
2010/01/04    4        4.00
2010/01/05    1        2.50
2010/01/06    1        2.50
2010/01/07    1        2.50
2010/01/08    1        2.50
```

And i want to fill with a binary(1 and 0) when the price reduces more or equal than 25% and during less or equal to 3days: 1, if otherwise 0.
Is there any way better than do it with condition IF?

the final result would be like this:

```
Date       Quantity   Price  Flag
2010/01/01    1        4.00   0
2010/01/02    5        3.00   1
2010/01/03    3        3.00   1
2010/01/04    4        4.00   0
2010/01/05    1        2.50   0
2010/01/06    1        2.50   0
2010/01/07    1        2.50   0
2010/01/08    1        2.50   0
```

Thanks!
PS: A csv with one product  http://speedy.sh/fbMYN/product.csv

Comment: Please state your condition more clearly. 2.5 is definitely at least a 25% reduction from 4, but the fifth line is not flagged.

Comment: Sorry if I don't explain very well the condition. Yes, it's more than 25% but takes more than 3 days

Comment: seems to be a good job for dplyr and lag but without data to reproduce it's going to be hard to reproduce it. Please provide a csv.

Comment: Sorry for my noob question, but how can I upload a csv here?

Comment: @ZéPinho you can't but you can upload one [here](http://www.speedyshare.com/) and link us to it.

Comment: I add the link with csv

Comment: i cant access the csv due to web blocking on my firm but can you check the code below and mostly the missing one in your result according to your condition?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I don't express very well my condition, but the output that i want is the output of my answer. If there more than 3 days with drop of the price I wanna fill with 0 in tohse days, like when pass to 2.5 (because are more than 3 days drop)

Comment: I mena on date 2010/01/05 there is a drop from 4 to 2.5, so why you do not put the flag to 1? So basically you need just to check the first drop of price and the 3 days following, is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok then from what you said

#### 1. Read CSV

`df <-read.csv("product.csv",header=T,sep=";")`

#### 2. Convert date and order it if needed

```
df$Date<-as.Date(as.character(df$Date),"%Y%m%d" )
df = df[with(df, order(Date)),]
```

#### 3. Add the binary column

`library(dplyr)`

```
df2<-df %>% mutate(Flag=ifelse( 
(lag(PVP,n =1)<=.75*PVP & as.numeric(Date-lag(Date,n=1))<=3) |
(lag(PVP,n =2)<=.75*PVP & as.numeric(Date-lag(Date,n=2))<=3) |
(lag(PVP,n =3)<=.75*PVP & as.numeric(Date-lag(Date,n=3))<=3) ,1,0))
```

#### 4. Output

```
filter(df2,Flag==1)

    Date Quantity     PVP Flag
1  2007-06-06       10   1.690    1
2  2007-06-07       10   1.690    1
3  2007-06-08       26   1.690    1
4  2008-04-16        3   2.490    1
5  2008-04-17        4   2.490    1
6  2008-04-18       16   2.490    1
7  2010-03-17        9   1.990    1
8  2010-03-18       17   1.990    1
9  2010-03-19       12   1.990    1
10 2010-03-22       13   1.990    1
11 2010-03-23       10   1.990    1
12 2010-03-24       21   1.990    1
13 2010-06-02       15 174.125    1
14 2010-08-04       20 174.125    1
15 2011-05-18        8   1.990    1
16 2011-06-01       10   1.990    1
17 2011-06-02        9   1.990    1
18 2011-06-03       14   1.990    1
19 2012-05-11       10   2.170    1
20 2012-05-12       12   2.170    1
21 2012-05-13        6   2.170    1
```

#### 5.Make it looks better

```
is.discount=function(dataframe=df,date="Date",argument="PVP",discount=.75,nbday=3){
         result<-0
         for (i in seq(1,nbday,1)){
                 result<- result | (lag(dataframe[,argument],n=i)<=discount*dataframe[,argument] & as.numeric(dataframe[,date]-lag(dataframe[,date],n=i))<=nbday)
             }
         return (result)
     }


df3<-df %>% mutate(Flag=ifelse( is.discount() ,1,0))

 all.equal(df2,df3)
 TRUE
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: @ZéPinho There was a slight error in my code. It was n= instead of k=